# Calling file names using regex in R

Tags: r, spatial, r-sp

I have a list of objects that I am creating using a loop. The objects are named Cij, based on the matrix row and column name they have.

I want to bind these Cij into a spatial line object using spatialLine() from the package SP.

I am trying

```
final_lines <- SpatialLines(list(lapply(nam1,function(x) paste0(x))))
```

where nam1 is a vector of the names Cij. But the function is giving me an error as its taking the result from nam1 as text rather than a data value.

How can I call the values of Cij rather than Cij as a string for the function?

Or if anyone can tell me how to call data values in R using Regex, that would also do.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `nam1` is a vector which contains character names of Cij objects and Cijs are `Lines` class objects then you can call the data values of objects by the function `get()`. I suggest you to make a temporary list (`mylines.lst`) with a for loop.

```
mylines.lst <- list()
for(tti in 1:length(nam1)) {
    mylines.lst[[tti]] <- get(nam1[tti])
}
```

Finally you can assign it to the `final_lines`:

```
final_lines <- SpatialLines(mylines.lst)
```

Comment: I get an error that says "Error in get(nam1[i]) : invalid first argument"

Comment: @Dinesh.hmn write `class(nam1)` if it is `factor` you need convert it to `character` with `nam1 <- as.character(nam1)`. I hope it will work.